# region of positive definiteness of a hessian matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, hessian-matrix

I am given a function f(x_1, x_2) = -cos(x_1) * cos(x_2/5). I need to identify the region in which the Hessian matrix is positive definite. I know that the first term of the Hessian matrix has to be positive and so as its determinant. From these two inequalities I get:

cos(x_1) * cos(x_2/5) > 0 ------------(1)

cos^2(x_1) + cos^2(x_2/5) > 1 ----------(2)

I am not sure how to proceed to identify the region. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hessian is symmetric so you can then check [Sylvester criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).